# Errors in next.config.js with next-compose-plugins package

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Next.js is throwing me errors relating to next-compose-plugins for my next.config.js file. I'm not sure why? I've tried re-installing all node packages.

The errors:
"The root value has an unexpected property, webpackDevMiddleware"
"The root value has an unexpected property, configOrigin,"
"The root value has an unexpected property, target,"
"The root value has an unexpected property, webpack5,"
"TypeError: Cannot set property 'styles' of undefined"

```
  /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */ const nextConfig = {   
reactStrictMode: true,   swcMinify: true, };
 
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");    
const withFonts =require("next-fonts");    
const withImages = require("next-images"); 
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");

module.exports = withPlugins([withCSS, withFonts, withImages], 
nextConfig);
```

Comment: You do not need `next-compose-plugins`, and `@zeit/next-css` has been deprecated for a long time (Next.js has built-in support for CSS). Make sure your packages are up-to-date and try rewriting the config to `module.exports = withFonts(withImages(nextConfig));`.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Next moved to SWC](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler), next-compose-plugins won't work. Instead you'll have to nest your config like this:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11162

Answer (score 0):

`next-compose-plugins` is now outdated and may not work correctly or work at all.

Please have a look at its successor [next-recompose-plugins](https://github.com/arklanq/next-recompose-plugins) which provides a clean and easy API for Next.js's plugins configuration and composition.

Here is a sneak peek:

```js
const config = new Config(async () => {
    await something();
  
    return {...};
  })
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin1(config);
  }, 'plugin-1')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin2(config);
  }, 'plugin-2')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin3(config);
  }, 'plugin-3')
  .build();
```

I highly recommend this package because it allows us to apply plugins seamlessly, the plugin application is less error prone, and the final code looks clean and consistent.